# How to use echo inside echo

Tags: php

I Have this code:

```
echo '<form method="post" class="product" action="index.php" id="addtocartproduct<?php echo $products->virtuemart_product_id ?>">';
```

I have to use echo inside echo and again I have to never use php in this line.
haw can I edit this line and make it like:

```
echo '<form method="post" class="product" action="index.php" id="addtocartproduct echo $products->virtuemart_product_id ">';
```

EDIT:
thanks every one for very useful help.
now I have another problem.what can i do with this line:

```
echo'<input type="hidden" class="pname" value="<?php echo $product->product_name ?>">';
```

Comment: `echo "<form method='post' class='product' action=index.php id='addtocartproduct $products->virtuemart_product_id'>";` Variables are interpolated in double quotes, you don't need another echo. But better solution is to not echo the whole HTML. i.e.: `//.. some PHP there ... then closing the tag; ?> <form action="index.php .... id="addtocartproduct <?=$products->virtuemart_product_id;?>">`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
echo '<form method="post" class="product" action="index.php" id="addtocartproduct '. $products->virtuemart_product_id.' ">';
```

Comment: echo can take any number of "arguments" so you can use commas instead of dots in that code. The advantage is that dot performs string concatenation before echoing which is an unnecessary step. If you follow this practice throughout all your code, you will save a couple of milliseconds.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to echo inside echo all you need is proper concatination.

```
echo '<form method="post" class="product" action="index.php" id="addtocartproduct
          '.$products->virtuemart_product_id.' ">';
```

**OR**

```
<form method="post" class="product" action="index.php" 
    id="addtocartproduct<?php echo $products->virtuemart_product_id; ?>">
```

if php tag is opened before then close it and then try above solution.

Such as

```
?>
<form method="post" class="product" action="index.php" 
    id="addtocartproduct<?php echo $products->virtuemart_product_id; ?>">
```

Answer (score 2):

you don't have to use an echo inside another, you can do one of the following:

```
<?php 

if (somethng) {
?>

<some tags you need in plain html> <?php echo "something you need from php"; ?> </some tags you need in plain html>


<?php
}else{
?>
<some more tags you need in plain html> <?php echo "something else you need from php"; ?> </some more tags you need in plain html>

<?php 
}
?>
```

or you can use concatenation:

```
$varsecondsentence = "second sentence";

echo "this is the fisrt sentence, " . $varsecondsentence
```

this will echo : `this is the fisrt sentence, second sentence`

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<form method="post" class="product" action="index.php" id="addtocartproduct' . $products->virtuemart_product_id . '">';?>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Variables](http://php.net/variables) in PHP are expanded (interpolated) inside double quotes. So you don't need to use `echo` inside your `echo` statement. It's incorrect -- both syntactically and logically.

The following should work:

```
echo "<form method='post' class='product' action='index.php' 
id='addtocartproduct.{$products->virtuemart_product_id}'";
```

Or just use string concatenation, like so:

```
echo '<form method="post" class="product" action="index.php" 
id="addtocartproduct' . $products->virtuemart_product_id . '">';
```

All these do the same thing, but I recommend using the first approach since it's cleaner.

Answer (score -2):

just concat var and string should work, then you only need one echo

```
 echo '<form method="post" class="product" action="index.php" id="addtocartproduct' + $products->virtuemart_product_id+' ">';
```

take a look in these pages for more documentation 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

http://be1.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Comment: This is not proper PHP concatenation.

Comment: thanks every one.now what about this one:    echo'<input type="hidden" class="pname" value="<?php echo $product->product_name ?>">';